# Looking for locally stored Active Directory computer SID. Does it exist?

Tags: macos, active-directory

In order to collate information from our Active Directory and our endpoint management systems, I'm trying to gather AD information via EPM. However, macOS doesn't seem to have much about the AD connection for EPM to gather.

On Windows, I'm finding the AD Computer Name, SID, and DN Path in the Registry.

On macOS (in the /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Active Directory/[DOMAIN].plist file), I'm only finding the AD Computer Name.

Name is not enough to confirm that the computer in question is indeed the computer in AD. For example, one could delete the AD object and create another with the same name in another OU. The (leftover) local computer information would not change, however, leading a strictly named-based process to associate the computer with the new AD object. Confirming that the SID was a match would avoid this, but I can't find the computer SID anywhere on the local macOS system.

Is there anywhere within the local computer that macOS stores more than what's found in this OpenDirectory plist?

(Note: Tools/commands that run on the client and retrieve that information from the Active Directory itself will be of *some* use, but many of these computers are no longer in the same network as the AD Domain Controllers, so they're not ideal.)

Comment: I don't have access to an Active Directory, but using [`dscl`](https://its-a-feature.github.io/posts/2018/01/Active-Directory-Discovery-with-a-Mac/) you might be able to retrieve this info: `dscl "/Active Directory/TEST/All Domains" ls /Computers` (the linked article shows an entry `SMBSID` which might be what you're looking for). You may also want to look into the directory `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/` (needs root privileges to access; contains plist files that may contain the info you're looking for).

Comment: The `dscl` utility requires an active connection to the Active Directory, which may be useful over time, but most of our computers aren't on the enterprise network and can't process a `dscl` command. Looking into the `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/` directories. Thanks!

Comment: Investigated `dscl` some more...it (and Directory Utility) allows you to read the `SMBSID` for ALL Active Directory computers directly from the AD. I suppose that some assumptions can be made with regards to the fact that this only works for computers that are AD joined in the first place, but is it still that... an assumption, not local verification.

The `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/` directories are coming up dry, too. Lots of user info, little (or no) computer info.